# django read dynamic csv file error

Tags: python, django, csv

I wrote Django python csv reader but it's not working properly. I can see the file is uploaded to the system, but I can't read it and I'm getting the error below:

```
Exception Type: AttributeError 
Exception Value:     'str' object has no attribute 'read'
data = csv.reader(open('tmp/tmp.csv'), delimiter=";")
```

When I am using as per above statically ,it's working but I need the dynamic one that I am receiving via file upload. I need your help because I am out of options to solve this.
I know that decoded_file, io_string and data variables are not working correctly but can't fix them.

```
def upload_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csv_file']:
        myfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)

        decoded_file = filename.read().decode('utf-8')
        io_string = io.StringIO(decoded_file)
        data = csv.reader(io_string, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
        for row in data:
            if row[0] != 'FP_Item':
               post = FP()
               post.FP_Item = row[0]
               post.save()
```

CSV File:  Not much because still import trials, only 2 lines.There was ; at the end but I deleted and retried still the same

```
5.Item try
Try
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try to read a string in csv.reader. you change your code in upload_csv:

```
def upload_csv(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csv_file']:
        myfile = request.FILES['csv_file']
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
        print "filename",filename
        data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename, mode='r'), delimiter=str(u';').encode('utf-8'), quotechar=str(u'"').encode('utf-8'))
        for row in data:
            print "row: ",row
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error  Exception Type: AttributeError
Exception Value: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Comment: I am getting this error at this line: decoded_file = filename.read()          It's not accepting to read filename variable.What can cause this ?

Comment: i edit this line:    decoded_file = fs.open(filename)         . try and tell me if works

Comment: filename is the name of the file that it is save. And you need open the file with the name of filename in fs.  You change this line in your code: decoded_file = filename.read().decode('utf-8') with this line decoded_file = fs.open(filename).read().decode('utf-8')

Comment: change code, i tried and works for upload file csv and decode fine

Comment: now I am receiving another error    Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: "delimiter" must be string, not bytes    ;                     line  of error     ;  data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename), delimiter=str(u';').encode('utf-8'), quotechar=str(u'"').encode('utf-8'))

Comment: why in your code you use delimiter=';'   and  quotechar='|'?

Comment: Even though I delete delimiter and quotechar I am receiving error. Normally I am needing delimiter because I am importing different colomns as well but I modified the csv for importing single colomn and I tried again and received the below error   Exception Type: Error
Exception Value: 
iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)

Comment: how is the data in your csv file?

Comment: I am now receiving error at line "for row in data: ", so at least it's now reading the file.I added what I have within csv to question          Value: iterator should return strings, not bytes (did you open the file in text mode?)   I also added my loop for saving to the django model

Comment: Yes now it works.:) Thank you very much for your interest.